# Adding int as a char to a char[ ]

Tags: c

Sorry if the topic name isn't very clear I couldn't find a way to express it.
So let's say i have this structure :

```
    struct filee 
    {
       ...
       int number;
       char filename[7];
    };
typedef struct filee filee;
```

and I want to initialize it with a function

```
void file_init(filee* x,int n)
{
    x->number=n;
    x->filename=(char)n+"ch.bmp"
}
```

but that doesn't really work so what I want is if for example I do this :

```
file_init(&randomFile,2);
```

It works this way:

```
randomFile.number=2;
randomFile.filename="2ch.bmp";
```

I hope that what I said is clear and thanks for the help!

Comment: note : `char filename[7];` is small.

Comment: regarding this line: 'x->filename=(char)n+"ch.bmp"'  in C, character strings cannot be concatenated using the '+' operator.   see the @iharob answer for an example of how to do it.

Comment: the char string 'ch.bmp' is 7 characters, (remember the trailing '\0' on the string)  then prefixing that with one (or more) digits will overflow the bounds of the filename array.  This results in undefined behaviour, which can/will lead to a seg fault event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `snprintf()`

```
int length;
int result;

length = sizeof(x->filename);
result = snprintf(x->filename, length, "%dch.bmp", x->number);
if ((result < 0) || (result >= length))
    error_TheTargetIsNotLargeEnough();
```

Comment: note : `snprintf` returns a negative value if there is an error